# C# Get index values of max value in 2D integer array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, indexing

Is there a slicker way? After populating the array with random numbers (and where the user determines the size of the 2D array) I got the max like this:

```
int largest = array.Cast<int>().Max();
```

Now to get the index values, the only way I could think was to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsize); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsize); j++) {
                if (largest == array[i, j])
                    Console.WriteLine("The index values of the largest value are {0} and {1}", i, j);
            }
        }
```

I was thinking there was a way to use the IndexOf method, couldn't find it. And I could be wrong, but a foreach loop doesn't seem to support index values.

Comment: According to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260935/finding-position-of-an-element-in-a-two-dimensional-array you did best possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chance for duplicated max values in your current situation. You could probably save yourself half a millisecond saving the message to be displayed to a local variable and printing this after the loop in the form of message1\r\n\message2\r\n\r\nmessage3. However if you're only interested in the first occurance breaking from the loop might be worth considering.

Either way, you're basically fine.

Comment: Yeah, the way the array was populated randomly the max value could appear more than once, and I would want all those indexes where they occurred. I'll have to rewrite the output so it reads a little better.