# If item is in any dimension of multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that, for example, is 2d and looks like this: `var arr = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"], ["6"]];'

When I run `$.inArray("4", arr);` or `arr.indexOf("4")`, I get -1 meaning it is not in the array. However, it is in one of the inner arrays.

How can I tell if it is in the array or in any arrays that are elements in the array? In other words in any dimension of the array.

Comment: @adeneo so, calling in array when an array is found as an element in the array? but how I do inArray or index of if that inner array isn't assigned to a var?

Comment: try flattening the array first, such as by using `$.map`

Comment: @KingKing How do I use map to flatten out an array?

Comment: This question has already been answered on another post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260935/finding-position-of-an-element-in-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var arr = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"], ["6"]];
if(arr.join().split(',').indexOf("4") != -1){
   // do something.     
}
```

`.join()` converts the array to comma separated elements and `.split(',')` creates a new array out of it, which is a flattened one. So, `.indexOf()` works now.

Comment: This returns `true` if 4 isn't in the arrays, but 14 is. This is not how you search for an item in nested array (converting to a string representation).

Comment: @lan it's not string representation, this solution in fact works.

Comment: @KingKing Crap, I was focusing on the `.join()` part and forgot to `.split()`. This does seem to work, as long as the input is a 2d array with simple numbers

Comment: the input can also be a string ***but*** it should not contain any comma, otherwise we will lose the boundaries between each actual element.

Comment: @KingKing Exactly, so this answer is very specific to this question/problem; the other answers can be applied to any 2d array. My original comment was downright wrong - I was looking at the wrong thing

Comment: @Ian the interesting point here is this can be used on a nested array of deeper level (not just 2), I've tested it. While other solutions just work for 2d array (but it's the OP's case).

Comment: @KingKing That is a good/interesting point! I just feel like there's a better solution than relying on the data not containing a comma (or replacing commas in the data and restoring them later), and I'd say that is recursion. There's still things to consider, for example the size of the array (because the `.join().split()` does a lot of unnecessary stuff and creates a whole new array object), the data the arrays hold (you might have to do special things, like when there's potentially commas in the data), etc. I know all these solutions work, but I wouldn't personally use them

Answer (score 2):

The better engineered solution would be to create a recursive function that searches an array for a value.

If the array is only two levels deep as in the example there is also a more convenient solution: flatten the array and simply use `indexOf`:

```
var arr = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"], ["6"]];
var flattened = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr);
alert(flattened.indexOf("4"));
```