# Using Array.IndexOf on jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, jagged-arrays

If I have a jagged array set out like this:

```
[0][0]{128}
[0][1]{512}
[1][0]{64}
```

How would I get both the indexes of the number. So if I tried to get `64` I would get something like `0,1` indicating the index of the item. I tried using the `Array.IndexOf()` method but I get `-1` as it isn't built for jagged arrays. Format of the output isn't important. It can be a string, two intergers, a byte array, anything.

Comment: Hi, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260935/finding-position-of-an-element-in-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> IndexOf<T>(this T[][] jaggedArray, T value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.Length; i++)
    {
        T[] array = jaggedArray[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            if (array[j].Equals(value))
                return Tuple.Create(i, j);
    }
    return Tuple.Create(-1, -1);
}
```

You can use it as:

```
int[][] myArray = ...
Tupple<int, int> position = myArray.IndexOf(64);
```

Or for matrixes:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> IndexOf<T>(this T[,] matrix, T value)
{
    int width = matrix.GetLength(0); 
    int height = matrix.GetLength(1); 

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            if (matrix[x, y].Equals(value))
                return Tuple.Create(x, y);

    return Tuple.Create(-1, -1);
}
```

You might still want to check for NULL values or NULL arrays, but that is up to you.

Comment: Why are you copying this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260935/finding-position-of-an-element-in-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: I thought the same Pawel but the top solution he provided is different.